# Calculating limit involving binomial coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, binomial-coefficients, jordan-normal-form

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} h^{(n-k)} ,  |h| < 1$$

I'm trying to evaluate this limit, but like the $h$ messes me up each time. What I'm doing is trying to prove that the infinite power of a Jordan Matrix has a limit when the eigenvalue is less than one. so in this case, $h$ will be the only Eigenvalue. I have absolute no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $k$ is fixed, the limit is $0$, since the binomial coefficient increases polynomially in $n$ and $h^n$ decreases exponentially in $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have

$$\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\\\
&\sim\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n}{k!\sqrt{2\pi (n-k)}\left(\frac{n-k}{e}\right)^{n-k}}\\\\
&=\frac{n^k\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{k-1/2}}{k!e^k\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{n} }\\\\
&\sim \frac{n^k}{k!}
\end{align}$$

as $n\to \infty$.  And $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^k}{k!}h^{n-k}=0$ for $|h|<1$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=g(a)$ where f(a), g(a) are finite, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)g(x)=f(a)g(a)$.

In this problem the for fixed k, the lim of the combinatorics tends to 1 and the lim of the h^(n-k) is 0 then the product of the two is 0.